# Pandas - Create new column from calculation over irregular string patterns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have some data in a pandas dataframe like so:

```
|           Data           | 
----------------------------    
|   10-9   8-6    100-2    |
----------------------------
|           1-2    3-4     |
----------------------------
|                  55-45   |
----------------------------
```

Now my question is, using pandas, what is the best way to do the following:

- Calculate the average of the first numbers before the hyphen, and the average of the numbers after the hyphen.
- Subract the second from the first, and place into a new column.

For example, for the first row, the value in the new column will be: average(10, 8, 100) - average(9, 6, 2)

I am guessing I will need to use some sort of lambda function, but I am not sure how to go about it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is that a single column of data?  Would you create code to create the input dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick. `split()` will get rid of all the white space. Also using list comprehension to go through all the tokens created by `split()` (e.g. `['10-9', '8-6', '100-2']`).

```
In [37]: df = DataFrame({'Data': ["   10-9   8-6    100-2    ",
                         "           1-2    3-4     ", 
                         "                  55-45   "]})

In [38]: def process(cell):
    ...:     avg = []
    ...:     for i in range(2):
    ...:         l = [int(x.split("-")[i]) for x in cell.split()]
    ...:         avg.append(sum(l) * 1. / len(l))
    ...:     return avg[0] - avg[1]
    ...:

In [39]: df['Data'].apply(process)
Out[39]:
0    33.666667
1    -1.000000
2    10.000000
Name: Data, dtype: float64
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make a function to contain the string parsing logic:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def string_handling(string):
    values = [it for it in string.strip().split(' ') if it]
    values = [v.split('-') for v in values]
    first_values = [int(v[0]) for v in values]
    second_values = [int(v[1]) for v in values]
    return pd.Series([np.mean(first_values), np.mean(second_values)])
```

Apply the function:

```
df[['first_value','second_value']] = df['Data'].apply(string_handling)
df['diff'] = df['first_value'] - df['second_value']
```

Comment: Thanks very clear answer, I will try and incorporate in my project.

Comment: @ConvexLeopard glad I could help.